# HTTP redirect (done via angular) to a localhost:8443

Tags: angular

I am getting an issue where an incorrect URL redirects back to a `localhost:8443` when we enter a non-existing page.

Angular handles this 404 by providing a `non-found.component.ts` file in the application code.  In this component, we have code that redirects that user to the /login page, but once the login button is pressed we are redirected to localhost:8443

Angular code is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.css']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
   localStorage.clear();
   this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
  }

}
```

For example:
If I type: https://dashboard.bggoplan.com/INCORRECTURL the site goes to the login page, and then once the login is completed is pressed, it goes to https://localhost:8443/

I suspect this is something at the gateway/conf.d level. (`appserver.conf` and `https-redirect.conf`).  Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Angular apps are SPA's and everything happens in your browser. Even redirections. You should double-check for your `routing` modules. Angular doesn't do any specific handling based off a component's name. The fact that you're redirecting on `ngOnInit` sounds kind of fishy to me as well. Perhaps you might want to move that into a separate function and bind the `(click)` event to that new function instead of doing such a thing in `ngOnInit`

Comment: Very likely an incorrect returnUrl somewhere in your login configuration, either client or serverside. Do a global search for :8443 on the client and if not there, look at your login flow on the server (and check your network tab for 301/302 statuses)

Answer (score 0):

in your chrome browser, paste this link

`chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

got to the

> Delete domain security policies, enter localhost, and click delete

now clear your browser or use this link to clear your browser `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`